# Sorting an ArrayList of Objects alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have to create a method that sorts an *ArrayList* of objects alphabetically according to email and then prints the sorted array. The part that I am having trouble with it sorting it. I have researched it and tried using `Collections.sort(vehiclearray);` but that didn't work for me. I was that I needed something called a comparator but couldn't figure out how it worked. Will I have to use those or can something like bubble sort or insertion sort work for this kind of thing?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
public static void printallsort(ArrayList<vehicle> vehiclearray){

   ArrayList<vehicle> vehiclearraysort = new ArrayList<vehicle>();
   vehiclearraysort.addAll(vehiclearray);

 //Sort
   for(int i = 0; i < vehiclearraysort.size(); i++) 
   if ( vehiclearray.get(i).getEmail() > vehiclearray.get(i+1).getEmail())

//Printing 
   for(i = 0; i < vehiclearraysort.size(); i++)           
   System.out.println( vehiclearraysort.get(i).toString() + "\n");

}
```

Comment: No, you need a comparator. What didn't work about it?

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: `Vehicle` instead of `vehicle`. And probably `printAllSort` and `vehicleArraySort`.

Comment: There is a lot of tutorials which explains how to implement a comparator for your classes. Try to check this one first : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: @arshajii is right. Read this: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The sorting part can be done by implementing a custom `Comparator<Vehicle>`.

```
Collections.sort(vehiclearray, new Comparator<Vehicle>() {
    public int compare(Vehicle v1, Vehicle v2) {
        return v1.getEmail().compareTo(v2.getEmail());
    }
});
```

This anonymous class will be used for sorting the `Vehicle` objects in the `ArrayList` on the base of their corresponding emails alphabetically.

Upgrading to Java8 will let you also implement this in a less verbose manner with a method reference:

```
Collections.sort(vehiclearray, Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getEmail));
```

Answer (score 14):

Although the question already has an accepted answer I would like to share some Java 8 solution

```
// if you only want to sort the list of Vehicles on their email address
Collections.sort(list, (p1, p2) -> p1.getEmail().compareTo(p2.getEmail()));
```

.

```
// sort the Vehicles in a Stream
list.stream().sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.getEmail().compareTo(p2.getEmail()));
```

.

```
// sort and print with a Stream in one go
list.stream().sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.getEmail().compareTo(p2.getEmail())).forEach(p -> System.out.printf("%s%n", p));
```

.

```
// sort with an Comparator (thanks @Philipp)
// for the list
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getEmail));
// for the Stream
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getEmail)).forEach(p -> System.out.printf("%s%n", p));
```

Comment: I think this can be simplified using `Comparator.comparing`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0):

In this link you can find code which will help you to sort arraylist of objects in descending and ascending order.

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: you have added a less informative answer to a question which has already accepted answer and is better also

Answer (score 0):

package srikanthdukuntla;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AlphabetsOrder {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String temp;
    List<String> str= new ArrayList<String>();

    str.add("Apple");
    str.add("zebra");
    str.add("Umberalla");
    str.add("banana");
    str.add("oxo");
    str.add("dakuntla");
    str.add("srikanthdukuntla");
    str.add("Dukuntla");

    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){

        for(int j=i+1;j<str.size();j++){

     if(str.get(i).compareTo(str.get(j))<0){

            temp=str.get(i);
            str.set(i, str.get(j));
            str.set(j,temp );   

     }
        }
    }

  System.out.println("List of words in alphabetical order   "+str);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

clearest

```
vehiclearray.sort(Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getEmail()));
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little more?