# Sorting an array alphabetically, but the array is full of objects, and I need to sort by a particular parameter

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have an object like:

```
public class Fruit{

private String name;
private int quantity;

    Fruit(){}
    Fruit(String name, int quantity){
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity= quantity;
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And I want to sort an array full of Fruit objects alphabetically by name. My initial thought, `Arrays.sort(a.getName());` wouldn't work, because `.getName()` only works on individual objects. One idea I had was put all the names into an array, sort those alphabetically, then run a loop to sort the objects using this list, but that seems absurdly cumbersome.

Any ideas? As you can tell, I'm very new to working with objects in this manner.

Comment: suppose this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471005/sorting-an-arraylist-of-objects-alphabetically) has the solution for your issue. suppose you need to implement `Comparator`. This may be a good place to [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property).

Answer (score 3):

Either you make your `Fruit` class `Comparable` by implementing the `compareTo` method, or you provide a custom `Comparator` to the `Arrays.sort` method:

```
Arrays.sort(fruits, Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getName));
```

This uses the [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method.

Comment: Ooooh, I *like* this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you redefine your `Fruit` class to implement `Comparable<Fruit>` so that you can easily sort a `Fruit[]` by each elements' respective `name` field:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    // Code here...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit fruit) {
        return name.compareTo(fruit.name);
    }
}
```

Now, you can call `Arrays#sort` on `Fruit[]` and it will sort them lexicographically by name.

Comment: Very smart and clean solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make your `Fruit` class implement `Comparable<Fruit>`; you can do it by [passing a custom `Comparator` to the array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)), like this:

```
Array<Fruit> sortedArray = sort(fruitArray, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
   public int compare(Fruit left, Fruit right) {
       return left.name.compareTo(right.name);
   }
   public int equals(Object obj) { return 0; /* you can ignore this */ }
});
```